# Are wrappers possible?

Tags: android

Can I get an app that only can do one thing : dial a specific number?

If it is affirmative, can one make an app  that creates and edits plurality of described applications?
When you run it the first time , it will ask for list of names with phone numbers, and then creates a bunch of icons: Mike, Steve etc. Each icon dials one person

Where can  I hire a programmer, who is capable of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. it is possible

You could create an application that makes configurable widgets, so a 1x1 widget that has a preference stored for the number to call.

If you're looking to hire someone then I can't see much point in going into detail as how this would achieved seeing as you'll be paying someone to come here and read this answer.

You could try hiring via a freelance website such as gun.io or any other site that comes up when you search for [find freelance android developer](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=find%20freelance%20android%20developer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)